# Get latest time for each day?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am not a big SQL guy, so I hope this question is not too stupid, but I couldn't find an answer yet.

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
LastUpdate                       |  TheValue
-------------------------------------------------
2013-06-25 06:44:18.530          |  1
2013-06-25 06:59:18.500          |  7
2013-06-25 12:51:18.530          |  3
2013-06-26 07:44:18.530          |  5
2013-06-26 09:44:18.530          |  9
2013-06-28 08:44:18.530          |  0
2013-06-28 11:44:18.530          |  1
```

As a result I want the last entry of each day with the value:

```
LastUpdate                       |  TheValue
-------------------------------------------------
2013-06-25 12:51:18.530          |  3
2013-06-26 09:44:18.530          |  9
2013-06-28 11:44:18.530          |  1
```

Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH TEMP as
(
  SELECT MAX(LastUpdate) as TempLastUpdate
  FROM yourTable Group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LastUpdate,111) 
)

SELECT LastUpdate,TheValue from yourTable WHERE LastUpdate IN (SELECT TempLastUpdate  FROM Temp)
```

Result

```
LastUpdate                       |  TheValue
-------------------------------------------------
2013-06-25 12:51:18.530          |  3
2013-06-26 09:44:18.530          |  9
2013-06-28 11:44:18.530          |  1
```

Explanation:-

1.We first group by date only without time

2.We take the maximum of that respective group so that you will get the latest one of the day

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, guess my example wasn't the best. The latest value of the day isn't necessarily the highest.

Comment: We do by day for only group by, but while getting the latest value we consider the whole value that is what the above query meant to be.See my edit

Comment: I assumed that the value will be the maximum by the end of the day, but which is not true, so this edit will work under any case :) see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79abd/5/0

Comment: This is working fine now, I have given the fiddle also, have a look at it @Feroc

Comment: This is working fine now, I have given the fiddle also, @Justin , I think it deserves the lost upvote.... :)

Answer (score 4):

Query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.LastUpdate = (SELECT MAX(t2.LastUpdate) 
                       FROM Table1 t2
                       WHERE CAST(t1.LastUpdate AS DATE) = 
                             CAST(t2.LastUpdate AS DATE))
```

OR:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM(SELECT t1.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(t1.LastUpdate  AS DATE)  ORDER BY t1.LastUpdate DESC)  tt
     FROM Table1 t1)a 
WHERE a.tt = 1
```

Result:

```
|                  LASTUPDATE | THEVALUE |
------------------------------------------
| June, 25 2013 12:51:18+0000 |        3 |
| June, 26 2013 09:44:18+0000 |        9 |
| June, 28 2013 11:44:18+0000 |        1 |
```

Comment: Very expensive Query. **:)**

Comment: @Luv I think there wouldn't be better solution, by comparing execution plans... Maybe with Row number over Date partition.. but again I always try to compare execution plans and usually these querys with subquery in where clause are equal to other best solutions. It's just my answer, I think it's better to get more different answers and choose the better.